# Using Device Authentication to Authenticate to an Azure Registered Application

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal

I am currently trying to utilize device authentication using a PRT through ADFS and Azure to successfully authenticate to an Azure registered application. I am using a .net mvc web app to test this. I have already configured and registered the machine to receive the PRT token and have registered the application to Azure. However, when I open the application I still have to enter credentials which should not be the case with device authentication. Are there any code configurations that I need to make to enable the use of device authentication for my application?

Comment: Hmm, so you mean your device is joined to the domain/AAD? Which browser are you using? Have you tried with Edge or IE?

Comment: Yup it is joined to both. I can see the AzureAD PRT and the Enterprise PRT when I enter dsregcmd /status in my command prompt. I am using IE currently to test. I just don't know what hard code (if any) besides the adal library I need to implement in order to use device authentication.